# INSERT into table if a different result does not exist

Tags: php, mysql, insert

I have a 'users' SQL table structure like this (the ID is randomly generated, not auto-incremented):

```
ID    name     deleted    lastActive
3242  Joe      0          20-6-2012 23:14
2234  Dave     0          20-6-2012 23:13
2342  Simon    1          20-6-2012 23:02
9432  Joe      1          20-6-2012 22:58
```

There can be multiple deleted (deleted=1) users with the same name, but only 1 undeleted user with the same name (so adding Simon is fine, but Dave is not). How can I insert only if there is not a record already with the same name and deleted=0, in one SQL query? I need something like this:

```
INSERT INTO users (ID, name) VALUES ($id, $name) 
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM users WHERE name = $name AND deleted = 0)
```

But this is not correct syntax.

Comment: why not simply 'undelete' the username?

Comment: @MarcB because it will be a new user with a different ID. Usernames are set to deleted after 5 minutes of non-activity so other people can use them, but I can't delete them from the table completely as I need to be able to link them up later for reports

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setup a LEFT JOIN with

- Subquery A containing your random number aliased as ID and $name aliased as name.
- Subquery B selects name = $name that is not deleted.
- LEFT JOIN A to B and return A.* if it does not have a right side counterpart for the LEFT JOIN

This is the query

```
INSERT INTO users (ID,name)
SELECT A.* FROM
(SELECT RAND() ID,'$name' name) A LEFT JOIN
(SELECT name FROM users WHERE name='$name' AND deleted=0) B
USING (name) WHERE B.name IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [MySQL's REPLACE syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replace.html).

Make sure that ID Is either a primary or unique key and create a index on all three ID, name and deleted columns.

```
REPLACE INTO users (ID, name) VALUES ($id, $name)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO users (ID, name) 
SELECT $id, $name WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM users WHERE name = $name AND deleted = 0
)
```

Comment: Have you added the mandatory "quotes" around the different string based values?

Comment: Have you escaped your content?

Comment: Yeah I've tried it as a mysql_query with quotes (not escaped but just using id=234234 and name=joe, and as a prepared mysqli statement, both give a syntax error at the WHERE NOT EXISTS... bit

Comment: joe is a string, you have to escape it

Comment: 'joe' doesn't need escaping! I _have_ put quotes around it if that's what you mean?

Comment: Sorry yes, this is what i meant, sorry i can't help you more than that without seeing the real code as is which is impossible in this case

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO users SELECT '1', 'Bob','','' FROM DUAL WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT ID FROM users WHERE name = 'Bob' AND deleted ='0' LIMIT 1)
```